# an algorithm to find a transform matrix between two matrix.

Tags: algorithm, matrix, linear-algebra

Assuming there exist two matrixes A and B that are both m * n, is there a method or algorithm that can be used to obtain a n * n matrix C which satisfies the equation A * C = B' (B' can be obtained by performing several steps of row swap on B), where C satisfies the minimum sum of squared error.
Or A * C = D * B, where D(m*m) is a row swap transform matrix.

Thanks.

Comment: Please be more specific on that 'minimum sum of squares' error; could you please provide an example? The row-swapping should not be too difficult; `B` should be of dimension `n*n` then, I think.

Comment: for example: A, B are 10 * 2 matrixes, since the dimension 10 is larger than 2,  I can use linear-algebra solve to get a C matrix (2 * 2),  see( http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/linear.html).  The problem is how can I find a proper order of B to get the best C.

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question correctly, you have two matrixes `A` and `B`, and you’re looking for `C` such that `A * C = B + epsilon` where you want to minimize `epsilon`’s sum of squares.

Your question seems to suggest you have some constraint on `C` but it’s not obvious what that is. But as you indicate in your answer, a linear solver will find a `C` that minimizes `epsilon`’s sum of squares. The solver doesn’t care what the ordering of the rows of `B` are: it will combine row-swapping operators (like `D` that you mention) into the `C` that it finds.

There are many different linear solvers and a simple function like `solve` has to choose which to use—you can always explicitly choose a specific solver if you know you want it. An expensive but very useful solver is the Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse: with `C = pinv(A) * B`, `C` is guaranteed to minimize the sum of squares of `epsilon` but *also* minimize `C`’s sum of squares. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Minimum_norm_solution_to_a_linear_system) explains when `solve` might return something different than this min-norm solution via pseudoinverse.